How to change exe icon
I have C# WinForms App in VS 2020.
How do I change generated EXE icon?
All information I found over the net says about going into project preferences, but when I do that I see XML with
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
(and so on).
I think that my project might be somehow broken, if that is so, how can I fix it?

I suspect you're double-clicking on the project. If you right-click on the project name and select "Properties" I think you'll get a different view.

1- Click on "Properties" in "Solution Explorer" Tab.
2- In "Resources" section click on "..." Button. (In the picture below)
3- Choose your icon file from opened window.

